# Glassfish installation cacerts.jks vs cert8.db

Tags: glassfish

I have an old Glassfish v2 installation that uses cert8.db truststore. I ve set up a new Installation of glassfish v3 to import the old one. I found out tha the v3 uses jks trustore (cacerts.jks).

Is it neccesery to change the trustore to *.db files ? If yes how?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If there are certificates in the cert8.db truststore that you need to retain, they will need to be added to the new truststore

Comment: Understood. The thing is.... is there a reason to prefer jks over db or vice versa? (for example security)

Comment: I'm not sure that modern GlassFish supports db format. jks is preferred since it is currently being maintained as the default for GlassFish. You should also consider moving to at least GlassFish 4.1 for Java 8 support. Java 7 and below have been out of support for a long time now. This is especially important when thinking about security.